# Help running chrome in sh file

Tags: google-chrome

I wrote a .sh file but I am struggling to get Chrome to execute correctly withing the sh file. I am able to get it running however every time I open Chrome with the sh file the program will hang until I manually close the Chrome window before proceeding with the rest of the program.  If I just open Chrome from the terminal window I get the following error:

```
mgranger@Xubuntu-Server:~/Documents$ google-chrome
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: option value of option force_s3tc_enable ignored.
[1054:1054:1223/154554:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(305)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
```

I am not sure what this means or how to fix it.  Please help I have already spent too much time trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you start `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable &` or without ampersand? Chrome is too smart to not end when its window is closed; it still keeps 8-10 processes for some reason. Maybe performance, maybe spying on us for NSA :)

Use & at the end, it will create background process. Also ignore its output, that's just verbose and not expected anyone to actually pay ATTENTION.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like chrome(chromium)GPU process is crashing in your instance while starting the chrome instance. Similar issue is reported in google by several other and that was not fixed.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=383314